# Infinite product measure via Riesz representation theorem

Tags: measure-theory, infinite-product, limits-colimits, riesz-representation-theorem

I am curious about how we can get the existence of product measures in the infinite dimensional space by using the Riesz representation theorem.

I am studying the Kolmogorov extension theorem by the book of Tao, [An introduction to measure theory](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/gsm-126-tao5-measure-book.pdf). At the page 241, he says, "This result can also be obtained from the *Riesz representation theorem*, which is covered in 1.10 of *An epsilon of room, Vol. I*.", where 'This result' refers to the existence of product measures in the infinite dimensional space. I searched the book he mentioned and there was only the result of Riesz thm, not the proof I want.

Here is the statement of the existence of product measures

> Let A be an arbitrary set. For each $\alpha\in A$, let $(X_\alpha, \mathcal{B}_\alpha, \mu_\alpha)$ be a probability space in which $X_\alpha$ is a locally comapct, $\sigma$-comapct metric space, with $\mathcal{B}_\alpha$ being its Borel $\sigma$-algebra (i.e. the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets). Then there exists a unique probability measure $\mu_\alpha$=$\Pi_{\alpha\in A}\mu_\alpha$ on $(X_A, \mathcal{B}_A)$:=$(\Pi_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha, \Pi_{\alpha\in A}\mathcal{B}_\alpha)$ with the property that
>
> $\mu_A(\Pi_{\alpha\in A}E_\alpha)=\Pi_{\alpha\in A}\mu_\alpha(E_\alpha)\\ \\$
>
> whenever $E_\alpha\in \mathcal{B}_\alpha$ for each $\alpha\in A$, and one has $E_\alpha=X_\alpha$ for all but finitely many of the $\alpha$

I considered at first that some construction of directed system of measure spaces would yield a desired linear functional as the inverse limit, but I noticed that even if I can get the linear functional, the Riesz theorem is not applicable because the space $X_A$ need not be locally compact when A is infinite.

More precisely, I considered the canonical projection map $\pi^B_C:X_B\rightarrow X_C$ whenever $C\subset B$ and B, C finite index sets, and we may get the pull back map on $C_c(X_C)$ to $C_c(X_B)$ by taking a composition inside, and again we may take the push forward map from $C_c(X_B)^*$ to $C_c(X_C)^*$, and we have the directed system of dual spaces. I'm not sure whether my reasoning is correct.

But anyway I'm stuck with the problem that X_A need not be locally coampact when A is infinite, since infinite product of locally compact spaces need not be so.(Maybe it is the problem of the Topology by Munkres)
How can you solve this problem?